# LibSVM for Matlab - Unstable results

Tags: matlab, svm, libsvm

I'm using LIBSvm 3.22 on MATLAB R2016a (but I've already tested also with R2017a) on a x64 PC, and lunching my code I've strange behavior.

I'm using a Pre-Computer Kernel (68x68, symmetric, all zeros over the diagonal).

Here is my code:

```
    %
    clear all

    % 
    % 
    E1=load('..\sani_bi.mat');
    addpath('..\libsvm-3.22\windows\');
D=E1.Error_fro_sym
D=D+D'
labels=[zeros(34,1);ones(size(D,1)-34,1)]';
results = [];
GACC=[];
dec_values_p = [];
models=[];
rbfKernel = @(Gamma) exp(-Gamma .* D);
for C = 25:27%21:30 
    for Gamma = -1.75:.01:1%-50:.01:25
        eC= 2^C;
        eG=2^Gamma;
        K =  [rbfKernel(eG)];
        szK=size(K,1);
        u_param = ['-c ' num2str(eC) ' -t 4 -q'];
        for i = 1: szK
            %
            ind=[1:i-1, i+1:szK];
            model = svmtrain(labels(ind)',[(1:szK-1)', K(ind,ind)],u_param);
            [predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(labels(i),K(i,ind), model);
            dec_values_p=[dec_values_p; dec_values];
            results = [results; accuracy(1)/100];
            %disp([i accuracy(1)/100]);
        end
        value=sum(results)/szK;
        disp(value);
        GACC=[GACC; value, C, Gamma,sum(dec_values_p)/szK];
        results = [];
        dec_values_p = [];
    end
end
E=sortrows(GACC,[1]);
save('GACC')
%%
clear all

E1=load('..\sani_bi.mat');
E2=load('.\GACC.mat');
GACC=E2.GACC;
addpath('..\libsvm-3.22\windows\');
D=E1.Error_fro_sym
D=D+D'
labels=[zeros(34,1);ones(size(D,1)-34,1)]';
results = [];
GACC1=[];
dec_values_p = [];
models=[];
rbfKernel = @(Gamma) exp(-Gamma .* D);
for C = 25:27%21:30
    for Gamma = -1.75:.01:1%-50:.01:25
        eC= 2^C;
        eG=2^Gamma;
        K =  [rbfKernel(eG)];
        szK=size(K,1);
        u_param = ['-c ' num2str(eC) ' -t 4 -q'];
        for i = 1: szK
            %
            ind=[1:i-1, i+1:szK];
            model = svmtrain(labels(ind)',[(1:szK-1)', K(ind,ind)],u_param);
            [predict_label, accuracy, dec_values] = svmpredict(labels(i),K(i,ind), model);
            dec_values_p=[dec_values_p; dec_values];
            results = [results; accuracy(1)/100];
            %disp([i accuracy(1)/100]);
        end
        value=sum(results)/szK;
        disp(value);
        GACC1=[GACC1; value, C, Gamma,sum(dec_values_p)/szK];
        results = [];
        dec_values_p = [];
    end
end


GACC(GACC(:,4) ~= GACC1(:,4),:)
```

As you can see, I do the same thing two times. However, not always the last command return the same thing.
Sometimes is ok: GACC == GACC1 ad it's returned

```
ans =

Empty matrix: 0-by-4
```

but Sometimes it returns something, and watch the two matrix I can see (for example):

```
GACC=
0,500000000000000   27  0,970000000000000   -0,418026223801469
0,500000000000000   27  0,980000000000000   -0,418081551411518
0,500000000000000   27  0,990000000000000   -0,418132655182850
0,500000000000000   27  1   -0,418184269051726

 GACC1=
 0,500000000000000  27  0,970000000000000   -0,233717714208454
 0,500000000000000  27  0,980000000000000   -0,233752196783965
 0,500000000000000  27  0,990000000000000   -0,233784292330333
 0,500000000000000  27  1   -0,233816355641198
```

and just hitting running again, I gain:

```
GACC=
0,500000000000000   27  0,970000000000000   159857,292875661  
0,500000000000000   27  0,980000000000000   159875,372503753
0,500000000000000   27  0,990000000000000   159891,859001955
0,500000000000000   27  1   159908,815885524    

GACC1=
0,220588235294118   27  0,970000000000000   -0,0149253624535754
0,220588235294118   27  0,980000000000000   -0,0149350999202524
0,205882352941176   27  0,990000000000000   -0,0149446308316416
0,205882352941176   27  1   -0,0149534857047891
```

And after some runs it turn back to the first result (no difference spotted)

I can't figure out why this happens. During my debug I found that the problem could be in the "predict" method, that looks like sometimes dec_value can diverge and sometime converge, but looking in the LIBSvm source I can't find any seed\random initialization, and the code looks deterministic (i.e. no optimization with random start or something else).

Could be a problem about the Kernel matrix (maybe precision problems?)?
K looks something like this (diagonal is all 1 obviously because has been exponentiated):

```
1                           2,54073447948936e-11    4,23480527542159e-12
2,54073447948936e-11        1                       8,81718110217103e-12
4,23480527542159e-12        8,81718110217103e-12    1
```

Thanks for support!

Comment: [tag:kernel] tag is for **Operating System** kernel (see a description of the tag). But your question is about other meaning of the "kernel" word. Please, use more suitable tag for your question. [I am not familiar with the topic of your question, so cannot suggest a tag for replace.]

Answer (score 0):

The libSVM uses 'C' random number generator (rand() function) for data shuffling in svm_binary_svc_probability and svm_cross_validation functions.

See svm.cpp:

```
Line 1906:      int j = i+rand()%(prob->l-i);
Line 2371:              int j = i+rand()%(count[c]-i);
Line 2408:          int j = i+rand()%(l-i);
```

So, you need to modify sources and recompile libSVM to get stable results.

You can also try my libSVM 3.2.1 fork with `-rnd` option (https://github.com/agdavydov81/antennaarray/tree/master/voice-noise-music/matlab/thirdpart/libsvm/src). In this case please use `lib` prefix for any libSVM functions: e.g. `libsvmtrain` instead of `svmtrain`.

Comment: rand() appear in svm_binary_svc_probability and svm_cross_validation. But:
- for the first point you access to that function only if you set the probability lunching the SVM: and I haven't (default value of probability param is 0, so skip the if)
- for the second, I don't use svm_cross_validation

I need to use specifically LibSVM, not any other tools

Comment: Hmmm... Seems you right. May be will be better to save trained models also with GACC. If the models are same (isequal), then the problem in svmpredict.